# How do you stop redis from changing the number format?

Tags: redis

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> zadd somekey 12.54 value
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> zrevrange somekey 0 -1 withscores
1) "value"
2) "12.539999999999999"
```

How do I keep the original number format in redis?

Answer (score 0):

Redis relies on client for number precision conversion, so this might not be possible to achieve using Redis default cli using python.

A similar thread for same :
http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?messageID=159190

Comment: I wrote a nodejs program to access these values from redis and print it and I get the same result as from the client.